# Bajaj Pulsar 150 decelarating problems while riding

Tags: motorcycle, throttle, bajaj, pulsar

2011 model which has run to 60000 kms and i use it on daily basis with regular oil change & maintenance etc...

Yesterday night i rode the bike close to 20 kms and then came back home , it was fine :)

But today morning when i start the bike it was normal and throttle was also good

But when i moved to 20 m and changed the gear to 2 , my bike was losing throttle and completely decelarating and similar things happened to every gear higher than 1.

But when i put it in idle mode or 1 st gear and raised it was normal sound and but when i change gear and raise the engine come to powerloss , loss of throttle and close to switch off but not switching off

I do not understand what is the problem with my throttle loss in engine which decelarates while running even if its raised to full but not in idle condition or 1st gear

My bike has oil levels normal

I suspect Air filter blocking,  carburetor dust accumulation,  engine coil failure , spark plug ignition problem or piston failure

Pls help me to identify the correct possible cause

I dont want to take to the service centre without identifying the problems myself,  as they charge heavy highlighting more problems than existing by fooling us :(

Pls help me :)

Comment: It sounds like it's starving for fuel. I would probably start by cleaning out the carburetor.

Comment: Same problem happens to me also..... Mine is 2012 model

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like fuel starvation. Air blockage would make it blow black smoke (choking). The problem is most likely the needle valve in the carburetor has something non-organic (like a speck of tubing material) in it that is blocking most of the hole and is being pulled in as the more demand is placed on it.

About the only way to fix it is to pull the carb apart and clean the needle valve (the float valve). To do this you have to get the needle out of the hole and flush fuel through it. If you catch a lot of 'stuff', you might have gotten some bad fuel.

Comment: Thank you :) but fortunately the problem is solved automatically

Comment: Why not give a little more detail. The question was answered based on info given. How can it be solved automatically?

Comment: @SuguMaran may I suggest that you stop visiting Bajaj Service Centre ? They are freaking expensive and not like they are able to solve all problems.

Comment: OK, I guess - if you say so. I have no idea what you are talking about. Bye.